# Bash dialog cancel button is returning with exit cod 0; so is escape key

Tags: bash, dialog

I've created a simple menu dialog, but the cancel button and escape key are returning 0 for the exit code. What am I doing wrong here?

```
exec 3>&1;
selection=$(dialog \
    --title "Main Menu" \
    --backtitle "$BACK_TITLE" \
    --menu "Choose an option to configure. Up and down arrows change selection. Use the Enter key to make a selection." "$HEIGHT" "$WIDTH" 5 \
    0 "Select Directory" \
    1 "Select File Extension" \
    2 "Options" \
    3 "Execute with current config" \
    4 "Exit" \
    2>&1 1>&3);
exec 3>&-;
exitStatus=$?
echo "selected: $selection exit code: $exitStatus"
```

the above produces when I hit the escape key or the cancel button.

`selected:  exit code: 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saving the exit status of the previous `exec` command, not of `dialog`. Put `exitStatus=$?` immediately after `selection=...`.

```
exec 3>&1;
selection=$(dialog \
    --title "Main Menu" \
    --backtitle "$BACK_TITLE" \
    --menu "Choose an option to configure. Up and down arrows change selection. Use the Enter key to make a selection." "$HEIGHT" "$WIDTH" 5 \
    0 "Select Directory" \
    1 "Select File Extension" \
    2 "Options" \
    3 "Execute with current config" \
    4 "Exit" \
    2>&1 1>&3);
exitStatus=$?
exec 3>&-;
echo "selected: $selection exit code: $exitStatus"
```

Comment: Ah crap! I knew it was something stupid. Don't want to admit how long I've been trying to figure this out. Thanks a ton!